# uniform convergence of a sequence $Q_n = \sqrt{n}(1-\delta^2)^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $Q_n = \sqrt{n}(1-\delta^2)^n$, where $0 < \delta < 1$, converges to $0$.

This is on p.160 of Rudin's Principle of Mathematical Analysis.

How to show that this is a convergent sequence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clearly $Q_n\geq 0$. It suffices to show that $\forall_{\epsilon>0}\exists_N \forall_{n>N}Q_n<\epsilon$.
\begin{equation}
\sqrt{n}(1-\delta^2)^n < \epsilon \\
n/\epsilon^2 < (1-\delta^2)^{-2n}
\end{equation}
We can find a candidate for $N$ as follows
\begin{equation}
(1-\delta^2)^{-2n}
= e^{-2\log(1-\delta^2)n}
= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{[-2\log(1-\delta^2)]^k}{k!}n^k \\ > 
1 + [-2\log(1-\delta^2)]n + \frac{[-2\log(1-\delta^2)]^2}{2}n^2
\end{equation}
Therefore we must just find $N$ such that $\forall_{n>N}$
\begin{equation}
1 + [-2\log(1-\delta^2)]n + \frac{[-2\log(1-\delta^2)]^2}{2}n^2 > n/\epsilon^2. \\
1 + \{[-2\log(1-\delta^2)]-1/\epsilon^2\}n + \frac{[-2\log(1-\delta^2)]^2}{2}n^2 > 0.
\end{equation}
The existence of such $N$ can be shown using properties of the quadratic function.